# access List within List and check index for item changed in 2nd list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get data from list within list

```
data1 = [['Once per day', '50 times per day', 'Once per week', 'Twice per day'], ['Serverless', 'Infrastructure as a Service', 'Hybrid Compute', 'Virtual Machine Scale Set']]


data2 = [['Twice per day', '50 times per day', 'Once per day', 'Once per week'], ['Virtual Machine Scale Set', 'Infrastructure as a Service', 'Hybrid Compute', 'Serverless']]
```

I am trying to check in which index the first item from data1 is in data2
for example

```
Sample Output
3
4
```

as "Once per day" first item from data1 is changed to index 3 in data2 and adding 1 to index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would iterate over the length of data1[0] or data2[0] and compare the value of each element. If they are different then you have found your index.

```
data1 = [['Once per day', '50 times per day', 'Once per week', 'Twice per day'], ['Serverless', 'Infrastructure as a Service', 'Hybrid Compute', 'Virtual Machine Scale Set']]


data2 = [['Twice per day', '50 times per day', 'Once per day', 'Once per week'], ['Virtual Machine Scale Set', 'Infrastructure as a Service', 'Hybrid Compute', 'Serverless']]
```

```
d1 = data1[0]
d2 = data2[0]

for i in range(len(d1)):
    if d1[i] != d2[i] 
        print(0,i)
        break
```

Comment: but it is returning length of data1 set not compare and returning index for the item in data2

Comment: I don't need length of data1 or 2 to be matched!! I want to find in which index item 1 from data1 is in data2 list

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a list within a list is done via successive square brackets like `print data1[0][0]` would return `Once per day`. The rest of the process would be done via for loops!

Comment: But how will i loop through to get this output?

Comment: I have Seen print data1[0][0] but i am not able to loop through list to get index as i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

A short way to do it :

```
L = [(data2[i].index(data1[i][0] ) +1) for i in range(len(data1)) ]
print(L)
```

**output :**

```
[3, 4]
```